# How can I set opacity for Sharepoint Prediefined DIV?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

```
As mentioned in title, I am not able to set opacity.
I tried using rgba(0,0,0,0.5) - not working.
also tried opacity:0.6; still not working.
```

I am using Sharepoint 2010, IE9 and Sharepoint Designer 2010

Comment: Can you please post the complete CSS declaration (selector plus rules) you're trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to make Main Working Area transparent. code is, <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"></div>